# Get total Downloads of an android application using API

Tags: android

How to get play store console statistics data using an API programmatically (Get total Downloads of an android application)?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/getting_started

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 specialized API's which allows to perform specific types of analysis to your app such as:

**Specialized APIs**
The Google Play Developer API contains several specialized APIs that allow you to perform specific types of analysis on your app:

1. **Reply to Reviews API**
   Allows you to view user feedback for your app and reply to this feedback.
   **Link:** https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/reply-to-reviews
2. **Voided Purchases API**
   Allows you to revoke access to in-app products associated with purchases that a user
   has voided.
   **Link:** https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/voided-purchases

Comment: Hello Sir, thank you for this, but I want the total count of download applications using an API.

Comment: Hi Shivani ! There is no such API where you can get that data ! Google has preserved that data to itself only.